# Switch between three View Controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm very new to Swift and am struggling with getting this to work. Right now the view will switch from blue to yellow and back to blue then yellow, etc. I need to add a third view controller, green, and so it will go from blue to green to yellow then back to blue, green, yellow, etc. Can someone help me figure this out?

```
   UIView.beginAnimations("View Flip", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.4)
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(.easeInOut)
    
    //switch view
    if blueViewController != nil && blueViewController!.view.superview != nil
    {
        UIView.setAnimationTransition(.flipFromRight, for: view, cache: true)
        yellowViewController.view.frame = view.frame
        switchViewController(from: blueViewController, to: yellowViewController)
    }
    else {
        UIView.setAnimationTransition(.flipFromLeft, for: view, cache: true)
        blueViewController.view.frame = view.frame
        switchViewController(from: yellowViewController, to: blueViewController)
    }
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that using delegation, what I understand from your question is that you have 3 view controllers. Let's say A, B and C.

You want to create following type of navigation:

A --> B --> C

Now you want to come back from

C ---> A

After popping to the A view controller you can again push B and C view controllers and that way your navigation will achieve required reading result.

You can either implement delegate chain between B and C do that or directly pop to specific view controller in the navigation stack. It's totally possible.

Comment: @Irony Any updates on this? Have you solved the problem?